# How to form network using tanimoto distance

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bayesian-networks

I have data like this

```
column-1   Column-2      Similarity_dist
chemical-1 chemical-2    0.6
chemical-1 chemical-3    0.1
chemical-1 chemical-4    0.7
chemical-1 chemical-5    0.3
chemical-2 chemical-1    0.05
chemical-2 chemical-3    0.65
chemical-2 chemical-4    0.75
chemical-2 chemical-5    0.4
```

. . such 16000 rows. Now I filtered them with similarity cutoff of 0.5, and my data looks like

```
column-1   Column-2      Similarity_dist
chemical-1 chemical-2    0.6
chemical-1 chemical-4    0.7
chemical-2 chemical-3    0.65
chemical-2 chemical-4    0.75
```

. .

I want to find interaction network among these chemicals. Does anyone knows method in R by which I can use chemicals as nodes and distances as edges and then form network? Any other suggestion? Any code?

Answer (score 2):

The `igraph` package has tools to make this easy. I *think* that you mean these to be undirected links between the chemicals.  If not,  just remove the `directed=FALSE` part below.

```
## Data
Chems = read.table(text="Column-1   Column-2   Similarity_dist
chemical-1 chemical-2    0.6
chemical-1 chemical-4    0.7
chemical-2 chemical-3    0.65
chemical-2 chemical-4    0.75", 
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Now that we have your data, we can turn that directly into a network.

```
library(igraph)
ChemGraph = graph_from_data_frame(Chems, directed=FALSE)
plot(ChemGraph)
```

[image: Chemical Network]

The weights are stored as an attribute of the edges (type `E(ChemGraph)$Similarity_dist`) and can be used as a label or change the appearance of the links.

### Addition

If there are many nodes and you want to look only at the connectivity of a subset,  you can get that like this:

```
## List the nodes you want
Wanted = c("chemical-1", "chemical-2", "chemical-4")

## Create the graph containing only wanted nodes
WantedGraph = induced_subgraph(ChemGraph, Wanted)
plot(WantedGraph)
```

[image: Subgraph]

Comment: thats excellent. One more thing Its so clustered together. Is there way I can plot selected row?

Comment: I assume that you are saying that with your real data, there are many more nodes and the picture is too crowded. You can plot just part of the graph if you want. I will add a note to the answer.

Comment: Thats very gracious of you @G5W